# What is the best way to draw a moving line/curve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I would like to draw "moving" lines using JavaScript and Canvas. Basically, I have a bezier curve I would like to draw, but instead of drawing the curve all at once, I would like to draw pieces of the curve over time so it looks like it is growing. A better explanation might be: I would like the line to start to the origin, and then move to the destination point over time. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: A series of `setTimeout()`s or `setInterval()`? What have you got so far? (Easier to suggest some changes to existing code than to do it from scratch.)

Comment: A possibly wonky solution, depending on your situation, might be to draw the curve behind a solid opaque block element, and then slide or blind animate the covering element to reveal the curve. I'm not sure I'd even want to end up with a solution like that, but it's an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for a way to do the same thing, and found the [jQuery Tween and jQuery Curve](https://github.com/heygrady/curve) plugins, described and demoed here: 
http://heygrady.com/blog/2011/07/20/animating-with-curves-in-jquery/

Answer (score 2):

I created a jQuery plugin called [jCurvy](http://jcurvy.com/) that allows you to place elements along a bezier curve.  You could use jCurvy along with the fadeIn method and a callback to do what you are talking about.  Take a look at the example I setup here:

http://jsfiddle.net/pFZss/2/

If you do end up going this route and you run into any problems, please let me know.  I'm pretty sure you'd be one of the first people to use the plugin, so I'd love some feedback.

Answer (score -1):

Use setTimeout or setInterval. You can also use animate function